# SQL Server HierarchyID: how to add multiple children?

Tags: sql-server, hierarchyid

Itzik Ben-Gan described here some simple methods how to work with hierarchyId data type.

http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/hierarchyid

He uses stored proc to add child to some root

```
-- Web Listing 2: Script to Create Stored Procedure usp_AddEmp
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_AddEmp', 'P') IS NOT NULL
  DROP PROC dbo.usp_AddEmp;
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid   AS INT,
  @mgrid   AS INT = NULL,
  @empname AS VARCHAR(25),
  @salary  AS MONEY
AS

DECLARE
  @hid            AS HIERARCHYID,
  @mgr_hid        AS HIERARCHYID,
  @last_child_hid AS HIERARCHYID;

IF @mgrid IS NULL
  SET @hid = HIERARCHYID::GetRoot();
ELSE
BEGIN
  SET @mgr_hid = (SELECT hid FROM dbo.Employees WHERE empid = @mgrid);
  SET @last_child_hid =
    (SELECT MAX(hid) FROM dbo.Employees
     WHERE hid.GetAncestor(1) = @mgr_hid);
  SET @hid = @mgr_hid.GetDescendant(@last_child_hid, NULL);
END

INSERT INTO dbo.Employees(empid, hid, empname, salary)
  VALUES(@empid, @hid, @empname, @salary);
GO
```

To add any leaf to the tree need to call this proc like this:

```
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid =  1, @mgrid = NULL, @empname = 'David'  , @salary = $10000.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid =  2, @mgrid =    1, @empname = 'Eitan'  , @salary = $7000.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid =  3, @mgrid =    1, @empname = 'Ina'    , @salary = $7500.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid =  4, @mgrid =    2, @empname = 'Seraph' , @salary = $5000.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid =  5, @mgrid =    2, @empname = 'Jiru'   , @salary = $5500.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid =  6, @mgrid =    2, @empname = 'Steve'  , @salary = $4500.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid =  7, @mgrid =    3, @empname = 'Aaron'  , @salary = $5000.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid =  8, @mgrid =    5, @empname = 'Lilach' , @salary = $3500.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid =  9, @mgrid =    7, @empname = 'Rita'   , @salary = $3000.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid = 10, @mgrid =    5, @empname = 'Sean'   , @salary = $3000.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid = 11, @mgrid =    7, @empname = 'Gabriel', @salary = $3000.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid = 12, @mgrid =    9, @empname = 'Emilia' , @salary = $2000.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid = 13, @mgrid =    9, @empname = 'Michael', @salary = $2000.00;
EXEC dbo.usp_AddEmp
  @empid = 14, @mgrid =    9, @empname = 'Didi'   , @salary = $1500.00;
```

My question is:

I have a table with list of leaves-brothers which I need to add to the parent 14 on the same level

```
declare @toadd table
 (
    empid   INT,
    mgrid   INT,
    empname VARCHAR(25),
    salary  MONEY
)

insert into @toadd(empid, mgrid, empname, salary)
select 15, 14, 'Itzik', $0.01
union all
select 16, 14, 'Jack', $0.02
union all
select 17, 14, 'Alex', $0.03
union all
select 18, 14, 'Mary', $0.04
union all
select 19, 14, 'John', $0.05
```

I can create cursor and call the proc  N times.
But probably it can be done more effective? Somehow in one query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that a string of the form '/[int/][…n]' will convert correctly to a HierarchyId. So rather than use GetDescendant to add a subordinate to a manager, take the manager's HierarchyId, call ToString() on it, tack on '{EmpId}/' to it, and cast it back to a HierarchyId (or just store it if the column is already of this type. Specifically:

```
with emps_and_mgrs as (
   select *, m.hid as mhid
   from @toadd as t
   cross apply (
      select hid
      from dbo.Employees
      where empid= t.mgrid
   ) as m
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Employees(empid, hid, empname, salary)
select empid, mhid.ToString() + cast(empid as varchar) + '/', empname, salary
from emps_and_mgrs;
```

This assumes that everyone's hid value is of the form "{manager's hid)/empid/". This includes David in the original example; rather than having a value of GetRoot() (i.e. "/"), he'd have a value of "/1/". Also of note, if you're going to adopt this strategy, I'd also store the manager's empid on row. That way, you can write a recursive cte that uses only the empid and manager's empid to regenerate all the HierarchyIds if something goes sideways.

Comment: Thanx Ben, in my real db I store id, parent_id in the table.

Comment: But...what if  replace 14 with 5? I.e. 5 already has some children and need to add these new 5 to right from the existing "brother"?

Comment: It's not a problem. Because EmpId is unique, each of the corresponding hierarchies will be unique. So, for instance, the record with EmpId = 15 would have hierarchy /1/2/5/15/ and EmpId = 16 would have /1/2/5/16/. The pre-existing row for EmpId = 8 would have /1/2/5/8/, which is distinct from any of the others.